# Error generating WSDL in intellij : ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.woden.WSDLException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-axis

I have an issue for 2 days straight now and I don't know how to resolve it, I have an axis 2 project under IntelliJ and I want to generate the wsdl for the client but when I try to with the Tools->WebServices->Generate Java code from WSDL ..

[Generate Java code  from wsdl...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcaNQ.png)

I have the following error :

```
  Retrieving document at 'http://localhost:8080/Axis2_Server_war_exploded/services/HelloWorld?wsdl'.
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/woden/WSDLException
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDLToAxisServiceBuilder.<init>(WSDLToAxisServiceBuilder.java:103)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.<init> (WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.<init> (WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.java:63)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.<init>(CodeGenerationEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:50)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.woden.WSDLException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 6 more
 Done
```

My service on the server side is the following :

services.xml :

```
<serviceGroup>
<service name="HelloWorld">
    <parameter name="ServiceClass">HelloWorld.HelloWorld</parameter>
    <operation name="sayHelloWorldFrom">
        <messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver" />
    </operation>
</service>
</serviceGroup>
```

HelloWorld.java :

```
@WebService
 public class HelloWorld {
    @WebMethod
    public String sayHelloWorldFrom(String from) {
        String result = "Hello, world, from " + from;
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
 }
```

The client maven dependencies :

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.woden</groupId>
        <artifactId>woden-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0M10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.9</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.9</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.9</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.9</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: `woden-api` dependency seems to be missing. Make sure [the path configured in the IDE Web Services settings](https://i.imgur.com/0JKL5LE.png) contains all the required jars.

Comment: I already set that up and when I've added the woden-api dependency, the error remains the same :/

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA and attach the complete sample proejct to reproduce the issue ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved it by going to **File->Settings->Tools->Web services** and set up the correct **axis2 binary disribution** :

http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/axis/axis2/java/core/1.7.9/axis2-1.7.9-bin.zip

(I had the IntelliJ IDEA one).

Comment: This fixed the problem for me as well. I had downloaded it from Intellij and even though the version number was the same it didn't work.

Comment: @apfalz glad that helped ^^